# Best practices for coding a PHP nav_bar file?

Tags: php, html

I'm wondering what the proper practice is in this scenario. I'm using PHP to load the nav_bar file but I'm not sure if the nav_bar file should contain the HTML and body tags in it?

**Option 1**

```
<html>  
    <body>
        <div id="header_div">
            <a id="header_a" href="index.php">
                <h1 id="header_h1">Web page name</h1>
            </a>    
        </div>
        <ul id=header_bar>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link1.php">link 1</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link2.php">link2</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link3.php">link 3</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link4.php">link 4</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link5.php">link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**option 2**

```
        <div id="header_div">
            <a id="header_a" href="index.php">
                <h1 id="header_h1">Web page name</h1>
            </a>    
        </div>
        <ul id=header_bar>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link1.php">link 1</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link2.php">link2</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link3.php">link 3</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link4.php">link 4</a></li>
            <li id=header_link><a id="header_link_a" href="link5.php">link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your page does not contain any other content, it is best not to contain  and implement the `<html>` or/and `<body>` tags, as this is would force the browser in re-assigning these tags.